# django: Can't save data to the model, psql error

Tags: django, postgresql

I have following model described:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank = True, upload_to='files')
    about = models.TextField(blank=True)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    solvedProblems = models.ManyToManyField(Composition, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    country = CountryField(blank = True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(UserRank)
```

where UserRank is:

```
class UserRank(models.Model):
    rankName = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    upLimit = models.IntegerField()
    downLimit = models.IntegerField()
```

I have added the status, country and avatar field later after describing model, so updated the database via sql.

Now database looks this way:

chess_problems=# \d registration_userprofile;
                                  Table "public.registration_userprofile"
  Column   |          Type          |                               Modifiers
-----------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer                | not null default nextval('registration_userprofile_id_seq'::regclass)
 about     | text                   | not null
 rank      | integer                | not null
 user_id   | integer                | not null
 avatar    | character varying(100) | 
 country   | character varying(2)   | 
 status_id | integer                | 
Indexes:
    "registration_userprofile_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "registration_userprofile_user_id_key" UNIQUE, btree (user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "registration_userprofile_status_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (status_id) REFERENCES registration_userrank(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "registration_userprofile_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED

The error code I see is:

> (, DataError('value too long for type character varying(2)\n',), )

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.5.egg/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 280, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.5.egg/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 320, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.5.egg/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 416, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/socket.py", line 274, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/socket.py", line 261, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer)
error: (32, 'Broken pipe')

I feel it happens because I incorrectly updated database to fit the model...But not sure what is wrong, and how to fix it. Same code works locally on mysql instance...But I have psql on prod....

Comment: could you please indent a little bit your code or the database schema ?

Comment: How is `CountryField` defined?  In the database, it looks like that's the one that is `character varying(2)`.  Are you inserting a longer string into that field?

Comment: Thanks a lot people. I increased the field which stores the country code, and victory was mine!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting you're using this: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/494/ and [as tcarobruce says] CountryField is a 2-char code that represents the country -- 'FR', 'GB', 'US' etc and you're trying to store the full string name of the country instead.